# Give Java application access to specific Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, clojure, google-docs-api

How do I give access to one specific Google Spreadsheet to a Java (or Clojure) application?
Read only access is fine. My idea is to keep data in a Spreadsheet that I and some collaborators can edit, instead of in a database. Is Oauth2 needed in this case, or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: how about NoSQL ? cloud or local versions

Comment: @SrinathGanesh The data has to be conveniently editable for other users. I think a spreadsheet is most convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Your post intrigues me, simply because I have been using Google Spreadsheet as my "simple centralized database" that I can query against from all my machines. That said, my approach was very rudimentary (written in ~2009) because I only read the published CSV link and I don't do any write on the spreadsheet from my app.

After googling around, it seems like this is doable. Have you checked out this link? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ It seems like you can use OAuth to grant/check access before performing read/write on the spreadsheet. And they have examples in both Java and .Net to accomplish that.

Comment: I chose the easy way out for now. Just published my sheet and I consume in JSON-format.